# Problem with Attachments in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I have this code below:

```
    reportPDF = doc.getAs('application/pdf')
    reportPDF.setName('Automated report - '+ rows[0][0] + ".pdf");
    
    var file1 = destinationFolder.createFile(reportPDF);  
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("19Rv2f-Ud4Ncdzu-1MT1vUmh49pOKfKZX");
    var file2 = folder.getFilesByName("test.pdf");

    DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).setTrashed(true);

    if(file2.hasNext()){
          emails.forEach(function(email) {
          MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Automated Report - " + rows[0][0], "Hello!", {
          name: 'Good Practices Report',
          attachments: 
            [
            file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF),
            file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)
            ]

                                       });
                          })
      }
```

With this code, I should receive an email containing the two attachments (file1 and file2). However, when I run it, I get the following error:

> Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 158, file "Email")

In this folder, I just have one file with the name test.pdf, but the code still still accusing error on **line 158 : file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF).**

Does anyone knows what might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that the reason of your issue of `Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.` is due to `file2.next()` is used in the loop. In this case, I thought that before `if(file2.hasNext()){` is run, the iterator might be finished.

So, when you want to use the files of `file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` and `file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)` at `attachments:` , and also, from `In this folder, I just have one file with the name test.pdf`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
if(file2.hasNext()){
  emails.forEach(function(email) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Automated Report - " + rows[0][0], "Hello!", {
      name: 'Good Practices Report',
      attachments: [
        file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF),
        file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)
      ]
    });
  })
}
```

To:

```
if (file2.hasNext()) {
  var file2Pdf = file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF);  // Added
  emails.forEach(function(email) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Automated Report - " + rows[0][0], "Hello!", {
      name: 'Good Practices Report',
      attachments: [
        file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF),
        file2Pdf  // Modified
      ]
    });
  })
}
```

- In this modification, the files of `file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` and `file2Pdf` are used as `attachments` in the loop.

#### Reference:

- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)